# How can I hide old commits from "gitk" after rebasing?

Tags: git, rebase, gitk

In `gitk --branches` or `gitk BRANCH1 BRANCH2` I can refresh the view with F5, but after rebasing or amending commits, the view retains the commits that are no longer being pointed to by any branches.

```
'gitk master origin/master'   Gitk after                       After restarting Gitk
                                  'git rebase origin/master'
                              and pressing F5 in gitk.

  I (HEAD,master)               I' (HEAD,master)               I' (HEAD,master)
  H                             H'                             H'
  G                             G'                             G'
  F                             F'                             F'
  E                             E'                             E'
  D                             D'                             D'
  | C (origin/master)           C  (origin/master)             C  (origin/master)
  | B                           B                              B
  |/                            | I                            A
  A                             | H                            :
  :                             | G                            :
  :                             | F
                                | E
                                | D
                                |/
                                A
                                :
                                :
```

Now, I know that I can remove the `D..I` commits by restarting `gitk` or by resetting the view from `View > Command line` by reconfiguring the view through `View > Edit`. But is there a more convenient way to achieve it?

Comment: My gitk is broken at the moment, but I thought Ctrl+F5 refreshed everything, including removing commits like the ones you describe

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is a shortcut for File->Reload

Comment: The problem is that `gitk` ran a `git rev-list` earlier and nabbed, into its tcl arrays, the hash IDs of the original commits, which all still exist. You'll need to convince it to run a new rev-list so that it doesn't have the old hash IDs any more. I don't use gitk much so I'm not sure offhand what triggers that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File -> Reload (Shift-F5)`

This will rebuild the commit list. It's slower than `Refresh (F5)` but will remove the old commit.